# How to remove SBARS_SIZEGRIP from Statusbar

Tags: c++, winapi

This is not as easy as removing the SBARS_SIZEGRIP style during windows creation. Even when not set, the statusbar contains a size-grip. I want to know how to remove it. I've tried everything from SetWindowLongPtr for both WS_* and WS_EX_* styles after creating the window.

Comment: There is a comment in wxWidgets's [statusbar.cpp (line 98)](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/src/msw/statusbar.cpp#L98) that suggests setting the `CCS_TOP` window style and manually position the status bar as a workaround.

Comment: Ill give that a try. Praying this works.

Comment: @zett42: the VCL in Borland/Embarcadero apps does the same thing (enable `CCS_TOP` when `SBARS_SIZEGRIP` is disabled). Although MSDN mentions these styles in passig, it doesn't mention this particular requirement of them.